# How to properly implement full-screen images perfectly stretching on all screens?

Tags: android, android-layout, splash-screen

When implementing a splash image which has such a design that image **cannot be** skewed or cropped if the device screen is of different resolution or size, how to perfectly implement this? Image must be a real full-screen without black background due to different aspect ration.

Shall we create splash image for **every device screen size**? This is how we do at the moment and it's pretty much work. So we go to [Android developer support screen advise page](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) to know what images sizes we need. you see, there are a lot of them.

Is there a better and quicker solution?

Comment: Depends if your image has _repeat areas_.. in that case just use `9patch` http://radleymarx.com/blog/simple-guide-to-9-patch/

Comment: or make a drawable with layers and you will compose it for different sizes (as opposed to using baked-in bitmap).

Comment: @AmulyaKhare NO, 9-patch is rarely possible for splash.

Comment: @Lukasz'Severiaan'Grela Did not get you. Are you suggesting to use XML file and recreate splash bitmap?

Comment: yes, drawable in which you will compose parts of the bitmap - of course you may have bitmap that doesn't translate into the layered composition.

Comment: @Lukasz'Severiaan'Grela We did it in the past but very few times. Most times the designer creates such effects on the splash that we're unable to reproduce it.

Answer (score 2):

just get the splash screen in  1920*1080 and put in xxhdpi android system will auto ajust it

Answer (score 1):

Stretch occurs when when try to fit an image into an image view of different `Aspect-Ratio`.
Create 2 or 3 images for major `Aspect-Ratio` and then use `android:scaleType="fitXY"` on your image view, for devices that uses different `aspect-ratio` than you specify it won't differ a lot so you don't get a noticeable stretch.

Most common aspect-ratio are:

```
2:1      // ultra wide ex. 800*400 screen
16:9    // HD wide ex. 1920*1080 , 1208*720 , 720*450
16:10  // wide
4:3   // old tv square-like
```

Comment: Cool suggestions. Where did you find a list of these aspect ratios? Or you simply divided the most common resolutions.

Comment: I deal mostly with media productions, and for mobiles, computers, tvs and cinemas all aspect ratios almost get near to this.

Comment: Hi, where do you put images prepared like this? I mean into which resource folders do you put them? thanks

Comment: if you open graphical layout in eclispe, and click on nexus one to choose screen you would find some common resolution, and from there you can decide which folders to put in, ex 16:9 in layout-xhdpi

Answer (score 0):

If you can prepare a image resolution 1920*1280 and put in drawable-xxhdpi, it would fit to any screen

Comment: What about aspect ratio?

Comment: everything will taken care by android resources

Comment: So you're saying I should use max size image and the system will do the rest? I think I tried it in the past and the system skewed image on any screen with a different aspect ratio.

Comment: And yes, can you show me where did you learn this from? I was unable to find any similar official suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Try to create a [9-patch](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/draw9patch.html) image and use it as a background of the splash activity/view/whatever. Put your fixed size logo (or whatever you want to display) in the non-scalable part of the 9-patch and let the other areas stretch to fill the view. Note that the non-scalable area (e.g. your logo) should have size that will fit the smallest display you want to support.